# Can this class be reconfigured to accept named parameters in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

### Background code

I have a class called `Result` that I'm using to pass on some error codes and error messages to an error screen.

```
class Result<T>{
  Result._();
  factory Result.loading(T msg) = LoadingState<T>;
  factory Result.success(T value) = SuccessState<T>;
  factory Result.error(T title, T msg, T errorcode) = ErrorState<T>;
}
```

```
class ErrorState<T> extends Result<T> {
  final T title;
  final T msg;
  final T errorcode;

  ErrorState(this.title, this.msg, this.errorcode) : super._();
  //final T msg;
}
```

This class is called as follows:

```
return Result.error("Error","Status code not 200", 1);
```

### My problem

Functionally it all works great.

The problem is I see myself in the future having to refer back to my class Result code to remember what each field represents which may become even more problematic if I want to add in more fields down the line

I'd rather convert this so that the fields are named

### My question

Can this class be converted so that it is called like this (with a name describing the parameter):

```
return Result.error(title:"Error", msg:"Status code not 200", errorcode:1);
```

Comment: `factory Result.error({required T title, required T msg, required T errorcode}) = ErrorState<T>;` See [named parameters](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#parameters)

Comment: @ΟυιλιαμΑρκευα Error: The constructor function type 'ErrorState<T> Function(T, T, T)' isn't a subtype of 'Result<T> Function({T errorcode, T msg, T title})'

Comment: @Mark You additionally would need to make a corresponding change to the `ErrorState<T>` constructor or make `Result.error` not a redirecting constructor.

Comment: @jamesdlin Sorry I'm totally lost.  Could you point me in the right direction?

Comment: @jamesdlin NM I think I got it working, just had to had `required` into the ErrorState:   `ErrorState({required this.title, required this.msg, required this.errorcode}) : super._();`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to change `Result.error` to accept named parameters without breaking existing call sites, you can't do that.  Parameters can be either positional or named, but not both.

If you're okay with breaking existing call sites, then you can just make them required named parameters.  Since you're using *redirecting constructors*, you either will need to:

- Change the signature of the *redirectee constructor* (in your case, `ErrorState`) to exactly match that of `Result.error`:

  ```dart
  factory Result.error(
      {required T title, required T msg, required T errorcode}) = ErrorState<T>;

  ...

  ErrorState({required this.title, required this.msg, required this.errorcode})
    : super._();
  ```
- Or change `Result.error` to be a non-redirecting constructor:

  ```dart
  factory Result.error(
      {required T title, required T msg, required T errorcode}) {
    return ErrorState<T>(title, msg, errorcode);
  }
  ```

(If you do want to avoid breaking existing callers, you could add a separate named constructor (or `static` method) that uses named parameters, and you could optionally deprecate the old constructor.)

As an aside, it does not make sense that `Result` and `ErrorState` are generic classes.  Do you *really* expect `title` and `msg` to not be `String`s?  Does it really make sense for the type of `title`, `msg`, and `errorcode` to be the same? (With the example you've shown, you'll end up with `Result<Object>`, which defeats the point of using a generic class.)